# Param Element in Object not working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, pdf

I have a very basic html page which takes a parameter to render a pdf file with the object tag.  I was seeing this page work correctly in Chrome and IE but failing in Firefox.  As a proof of concept I broke it down into an even simpler scenario which works in Chrome/IE and fails in Firefox.

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">
    <param name="src" value="myFile.pdf">
</object>
```

However if I use something like the below block then it renders fine in all browsers.  Any ideas why the example above wouldn't work in Firefox?

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" data="myFile.pdf">
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the data attribute is the standard way of specifying the file. According to [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) the data attribute is required on the object tag.